# MouseHover event on custom usercontrol c#

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I created a usercontrol textbox named `ucTextBox` contains a label, a textbox and two buttons. I put it many in my form.

Now I want to attach a MouseHover event on each `ucTextBox`,`TextBox` and `MaskedTextBox` in my form.

I do this :

```
public void AttachHoverEvent(Control CTrl)
        {
            foreach (Control c in CTrl.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox || c is MaskedTextBox)
                {
                    c.MouseHover += new EventHandler(afficheDictionnaireChamp);
                    c.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(desafficheDictionnaireChamp);
                    continue;
                }
                if (c is ucTextBox)
                {
                    c.MouseHover += new EventHandler(afficheDictionnaireChamp);
                    c.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(desafficheDictionnaireChamp);
                    continue;
                }
                if (c.HasChildren)
                {
                    AttachHoverEvent(c);
                }
            }
        }
```

Note : I put `ucTextBox` in other condition to put a breakpoint and the condition is true.

My code works correctly for `TextBox` and `MaskedTextBox` but don't work on my 
`ucTextBox` (Nothing happen).

I try to add this in my `ucTextBox` class :

```
private void txbValeur_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MouseHover != null)
         this.MouseHover(this, e);
}
```

This my target events function :

```
public void afficheDictionnaireChamp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionnaire dico = new Dictionnaire();
            Control snd = (Control)sender;
            string table = dico.getNomTable(this.Name, snd.Name);
            string champ = dico.getNomChamp(this.Name, snd.Name);
            if (table != "" && champ != "")
                Globals.FormMain.tslTable.Text = table + " - " + champ;
            else
                Globals.FormMain.tslTable.Text = "";
        }

        public void desafficheDictionnaireChamp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.FormMain.tslTable.Text = "";
        }
```

If someone got an idea where the problem can from ?

Thanks in advance !

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your parent controls background to "Transparent"

Comment: Don't change anything